# Flutter 'get' function does not fetch the content of the website

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, dart-pub

To make a network request, I use

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Response response = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin');
print(response.body);
Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

the `response.body` should return a map,

```
{"abbreviation":"CET","client_ip":"64.185.235.18","datetime":"2020-12-24T13:14:09.198194+01:00","day_of_week":4,"day_of_year":359,"dst":false,"dst_from":null,"dst_offset":0,"dst_until":null,"raw_offset":3600,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin","unixtime":1608812049,"utc_datetime":"2020-12-24T12:14:09.198194+00:00","utc_offset":"+01:00","week_number":52}
```

but it actually returns

```
I/flutter (14782): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (14782):  <html>
I/flutter (14782):    <head>    
I/flutter (14782):      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
I/flutter (14782):      <meta charset="utf-8">
I/flutter (14782):      <title>Application Error</title>
I/flutter (14782):      <style media="screen">
I/flutter (14782):        html,body,iframe {
I/flutter (14782):          margin: 0;
I/flutter (14782):          padding: 0;
I/flutter (14782):        }
I/flutter (14782):        html,body {
I/flutter (14782):          height: 100%;
I/flutter (14782):          overflow: hidden;
I/flutter (14782):        }
I/flutter (14782):        iframe {
I/flutter (14782):          width: 100%;
I/flutter (14782):          height: 100%;
I/flutter (14782):          border: 0;
I/flutter (14782):        }
I/flutter (14782):      </style>
I/flutter (14782):    </head>
I/flutter (14782):    <body>
I/flutter (14782):      <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
I/flutter (14782):    </body>
I/flutter (14782):  </html>
I/flutter (14782): caught error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (14782): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (14782): ^
```

Actually the code gives both results but I have no idea why. For the same code sometimes I get the first result and sometimes I get the second.

ps, I am following the tutorial of the Net Ninja on YouTube, and I am pretty sure I write basically the same code as him, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make GET requests to the API and it seems to give an error sometimes as you mentioned. The API you are trying to call is maybe having some errors internally and it's not your code's fault. The API is hosted on Heroku and whenever the API server crashes or some errors occur, they send an HTML error page instead and that is what you are receiving. I did notice that it works sometimes and other times, it shows an error. So your code is probably working fine, it's just some problem with the API itself.